# Regarding mass insertion and helicity (?) flip

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, helicity

I am reading Grozin's book "Lectures on QED and QCD: Practical Calculation and Renormalization of One- and Multi-loop Feynman Diagrams" and specifically, I want to understand a paragraph on page 96 (the paragraph between equations 4.57 and 4.58):

> The electron mass anomalous dimension can be found in a similar way. We can calculate
> $\Sigma_{s}(p^{2})$ at two loops (neglecting $m^{2}$) by retaining $m_{0}$ in the numerator of a single electron propagator in Fig. 4.13 and setting $m_{0} → 0$ in all the other places. This single $m_{0}$ has to be somewhere along the electron line which goes through all the diagrams, not in the electron loop in the first diagram: we need one helicity flip of the external electron, and one helicity flip in a loop yields zero contribution.

These are the diagrams that he mentions in the figure:

[image: 2-loop electron self-energy contributions.]

I understand the following (please, correct me): if I take for example the first diagram (let's call it "rainbow diagram"), I just have to leave the mass in one of the propagators. In this case, I am only going to leave the mass of the propagator that has the X and I will do m→0 in the rest:

[image: Do not confuse the X with the notation for counterterms.]

By doing this, I am going to have a helicity flip for the external electron.

My first question (obviously) is: Did I understand what the paragraph says? but beyond that: Why does this flip happen? Why is it enough if I leave it on just one propagator? Can anyone give me more references for it? (something other than Grozin's book)